# How to send GET request without downloading response content using node-requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-request

I'm currently learning node and i'm looking for HTTP library that would allow me to send GET request, without downloading server response content (body).

I need to send very large amount of http requests every minute. However i do not need to read their content (also to save bandwidth). I can't use HEAD for this purpose.

Is there any way to avoid downloading response body using node-requests, or perhaps any other library - could be used?

My sample code using node-request:

```
const options = {
    url: "https://google.com",
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
    }
}

//How to avoid downloading a whole response?

function callback(err, response, body) {
    console.log(response.request.uri.host + '   -   ' + response.statusCode);
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP GET` by standard fetches the file content, you cannot avoid downloading(getting response) it but you can ignore it. Which is basically what you are doing.

```
request(options, (err, response, body)=>{
   //just return from here don't need to process anything
});
```

**EDIT1:**
To just use some bytes of the response, you can use `http.get` and get the data using the `data` event. From the [`doc`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

```
http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    //this is when the response will end
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

Comment: You can just read first chunk then ignore the rest by closing connection. I know it's possible in different languages (such as python requests) to avoid downloading the body and only fetching response headers. I'm looking to achieve similar in node.

Comment: Then use the `http.get` and add a `data` event.